# Mac mini 2011 mid - temperature issue

Tags: mac-mini, cpu, temperature

I have a mid-2011 Mac mini with an Intel i5 2.3 GHz processor.

When I checked the temperature, it was 90 degrees Celcius. The computer was running for three days. It didn’t work on anything.

Is this temperature okay?

Comment: 1. Check the fan. Make sure it's not clogged with dust. Computers are not dust proof and over time, they accumulate dust and debris that sticks to the blades, curbing their efficacy. You should clean out your fan. 90% of heat issues with regards to old computers are due to a restriction of airflow. 2. Make sure the exhaust is not blocked by dust or debris. On the mini, it is located on the back, underneath the peripheral and power connections. 3. Ensure the fan is operational. 4. Make sure the heatsink isn't warped. If it is, it will reduce it's efficacy to transfer heat away from the CPU.

Comment: And no, 90 degrees celsius is high. But then again, you have to factor in ambient room temperature and CPU usage. Also, how did you establish it was running at 90 degrees celsius?

Comment: what do you men by: Make sure the heatsink isn't warped? I downloaded a program and I check the temperature...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this app](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23049/smcfancontrol) to test if your fan works.

but if the problem is not solved you can replace the thermal paste.

Comment: I'm gonna try it and let you know, with the result.

Comment: well the fans are ok